# How to randomize order of if/elif statements?

Tags: python, function, lambda

First, a little background so you know what I'm trying to do. I am creating a pronounceable word generator. To make the words pronounceable, only certain sets of letters may follow members of another set of letters. For example, a word cannot begin with 'dtb'. This was easy enough to implement with a line of if statements to append a letter if conditions are met within the word. However, since this is a random word generator, I would like to randomize the order that the if/elif statements are executed in. I figured the best way would be to have a list of functions (where each function represents an if statement or rule), shuffle the list, and iterate through until a condition is met. This could be accomplished by explicitly defining functions like below for each rule:

```
string = ''
def rule1():
    string += random_letter
    if string[0] in letter_set_A:
        string += random_from_letter_set_B
    return string
```

I would rather not do this however, since I would end up with over a dozen explicit functions tied to names I don't need. I looked further into lambdas to make implicit functions in a list, but they do not support assignments like I use above.

**Is it possible** to create a list of complex functions like above that can be called in the format `my_list[i]()` without defining them explicitly? If not, how can I randomize the execution order  of the if/elif statements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose to have a dictionary `key:value` where given a char `c` as a key you have as a value a list with the allowed chars to follow.
In such a case, you could do something like

```
import random

allowed = {'a':['b'],'b':['c'],'c':['a']}

n_chars = 4

word = random.choice(list(allowed.keys()))

while len(word) < n_chars:
    word += random.choice(allowed[word[-1]])
```

The same method works in case of more complex functions like as follows:

```
import random

def f1(): 
    return "a"
def f2(): 
    return "b"
def f3(): 
    return "c"  

allowed = {'a':[f1,f2],'b':[f2,f3],'c':[f3,f1]}

n_chars = 4

word = random.choice(list(allowed.keys()))

while len(word) < n_chars:
    word += random.choice(allowed[word[-1]])()
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can to this.  Everything in Python is an object; you can have a list of functions just as easily as, say, a list of dictionaries.  This would be something like

```
rule_table = [
    rule1, rule2, rule3,
    ...
]
```

And then you could use `random.choice` or other method to get a function to call, just as you suggested.

Since you have a formal set of rules, you might get better structure from reading about formal grammars.  There are a lot of tools available to turn a set of locally-sensitive sequence rules into various acceptable strings.  You might also want to look into Markov chains, for probabilistic changes in the state of a system.

Is that enough to keep you busy for the week?